# Cannot Run SubWCRev on Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm facing an issue with Jenkins 1.6 with Subversion plugin 2.5.4 and Turtoise SVN 1.8.
The prebuild compiling is stuck on SubWCRev.

Any idea?

Comment: Show **information**, forget cry. There is your pre-build definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to run svn cleanup on Jenkins command then SubWCRev runs smooth.